# Yii - CDbHttpSession, session table before login

Tags: php, apache, session, yii

I follow [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/751/check-users-online-user-last-activity-user-last-ip/) tutorial to create my user online list.
In my local MAMP server on Mac OSX it work fine, but if I tried to put in Ubuntu server, I got this error (at the index, without logged in):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbCommand failed    to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'session' already exists.
```

I can catch the exception but I would to know because in OSX it works fine but in Ubuntu it's not works.

I think it may be something in Apache or other config: is it possible ?
Is session created before login ? The component need a user_id (not null) in the session table so I think there is anything I don't understand.
In both php.ini I set session.auto_start = 0.

Comment: Change session table name editing the sessionTableName key value, to avoid the collision of table names.

Comment: I have only one session table. I tried to drop it (the component create it automatically) but in Mac OSX this create it call once, in Ubuntu twice.
Is it possibile ?

Comment: Are you sure is it something created on the fly? If on Ubuntu it is a system table you shouldn't try to drop it, otherwise things would stop working... I dunno, maybe I don't understand what you are trying to explain...

Comment: I use this component https://github.com/frazelli/DbHttpSession/blob/master/DbHttpSession.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is that in those 2 servers you have slight differences, and among them the table 'session' which is already available in the Ubuntu server, and is probably handled for a total different reason against what you need, while in your MAC env there is no such thing as 'session' table.

The easy and clean way I can think of to solve the collision of names is to rename your table name from 'session' to 'mysession' changing the config setting this way:

```
'session' => array (
  'class' => 'application.components.DbHttpSession',
  'connectionID' => 'db',
  'sessionTableName' => 'mysession',
  'userTableName' => 'user'
),
```

And update every occurrence of the table name (like in queries) in your code.
This way the collision should be gone and everything should work fine.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Do you mean another session named table created from server config ? I'll try to change the name....